# Using a Edge Detector as a Feature Vector in SVM

Tags: svm, edge-detection

I am interested in using a support vector machine to classify curves in a image. For my feature vector, I was going to use a Canny edge detector since it would represent the edge I am interested in, but I am unsure how to represent that data as a vector. Does anyone know who to utilize a series of data from a edge detector as a feature in SVM?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had this same question. From what I've found so far, some options for going from edges to a feature vector are histograms of oriented gradients and edge oriented histograms, where you build a histogram showing the distribution of edges with varying angles present in the image.

Here's the Wikipedia page for HOG:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients

This question is what I finally found that clued me in on HOG and EOH:
[Histogram of Oriented Gradients vs Edge Orientation Histograms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505234/histogram-of-oriented-gradients-vs-edge-orientation-histograms)

Hopefully this can help someone else. I had the same question, and it was surprisingly difficult to track down an answer (I must have been using the wrong search terms, coming from a non-image processing background).